# Is there an example of Ix.NET (System.Interactive) somewhere?

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation, rx.net, system.interactive

I have an async method, say:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync()
{

}
```

and would be called from:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
{
    foreach (var item in something)
    {
        var result = await GetAsync();
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

The above syntax is not valid but basically I am after asynchronous generators. I know it can be handled via Observables. I did experiment with Rx.NET and it worked to some extent. But I am trying to avoid the complexity it brings to codebase, and more importantly the above requirement is still essentially not a reactive system (ours is still pull based). For e.g. I would only listen to the incoming async streams for a certain time and I have to stop the producer (not just unsubscribe the consumer) from the consumer side.

I can invert the method signature like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Task<T>> GetAllAsync()
```

But this makes doing LINQ operations bit tricky without blocking. I want it to be non-blocking as well as without loading the entire thing into memory. This library: [AsyncEnumerable](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable) does exactly what I am looking for but how can the same be done with [Ix.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive)? They are meant for the same thing I believe.

In other words, how can I make use of Ix.NET to generate an `IAsyncEnumerable` when dealing with `await`? Like,

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable GetAllAsync()
{
    foreach (var item in something)
    {
        var result = await GetAsync();
        return // what?
    }
}
```

Comment: Found an extension library here for Ix.NET which helps me with this: https://github.com/CXuesong/AsyncEnumerableExtensions

Comment: This link https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/linq-to-objects-interactive-extensions-ix answers it as well.

Comment: This link is helpful as well: https://stu.dev/iasyncenumerable-introduction/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edited)

Using System.Linq.Async 4.0.0 from NuGet, now you can use `SelectAwait`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
            await GetAllAsync().ForEachAsync((x) => Console.WriteLine(x)));

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }

    static IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var something = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        return something
            .ToAsyncEnumerable()
            .SelectAwait(async (x) => await GetAsync(x));
    }

    static async Task<string> GetAsync(int item)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // heavy
        return "got " + item;
    }
}
```

---

(Obsolete)

Using System.Interactive.Async 3.2.0 from NuGet, how about this? Currently `Select()` does not support async lambda, you have to implement it by yourself.

[Better support for async - Task based overloads for AsyncEnumerable](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/194)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
            await GetAllAsync().ForEachAsync((x) => Console.WriteLine(x)));

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }

    static IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var something = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        return something.SelectAsync(async (x) => await GetAsync(x));
    }

    static async Task<string> GetAsync(int item)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // heavy
        return "got " + item;
    }
}

static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> SelectAsync<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, Task<TResult>> selector)
    {
        return AsyncEnumerable.CreateEnumerable(() =>
        {
            var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
            var current = default(TResult);
            return AsyncEnumerable.CreateEnumerator(async c =>
                {
                    var moveNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
                    current = moveNext
                        ? await selector(enumerator.Current).ConfigureAwait(false)
                        : default(TResult);
                    return moveNext;
                },
                () => current,
                () => enumerator.Dispose());
        });
    }
}
```

The extension method is quoted from this sample. https://github.com/maca88/AsyncGenerator/issues/94#issuecomment-385286972

Comment: This example does not compile with v4 of System.Interactive.Async